# Ruby on Rails: Access values from form in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

How would I get all the values in the form input fields below by iterating through `ans[n]` where `n = 1...3` in a controller?

```
<input type="text" name="ans[1]" value="Test 1">
<input type="text" name="ans[2]" value="Test 2">
<input type="text" name="ans[3]" value="Test 3">
```

Comment: (I guess) `params[:ans]` should be an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop on this params by doing this in your controller:

```
#controller
params[:ans].each do |value|
  puts value # should print the values for each input
end
```

If the `params[:ans]` is an array of hashes, you can access to its attributes like this:

```
params[:ans].each do |answer_attributes|
  puts answer_attributes['1']
end
```

Comment: If params[:ans] is this array: { '1' => 'Test } , how do I access 'Test' ?

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the values of the param hash.

```
params[:ans].values.each do |value|
  puts value
end
```